# Creating a Stumbleupon button with a Single URL

Tags: stumbleupon

I'd like to be able to have the stumbleupon button on all my site pages, but always have it "Stumble" my home page.  How can I add this functionality to the Button?

**Here's what Stumbleupon gives me:**

< !-- Place this tag where you want the su badge to render -->

```
< su:badge layout="5" >< /su:badge >
```

< !-- Place this snippet wherever appropriate -->

```
< script type="text/javascript"><br>
  (function() {
    var li = document.createElement('script'); li.type = 'text/javascript'; li.async = true;
    li.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https:' : 'http:') + '//platform.stumbleupon.com/1/widgets.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(li, s);
  })();
< /script>
```

Here's my site [fairivy.com](http://www.fairivy.com)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Where you want the badge to show, edit the code from this:

```
    <su:badge layout="5"></su:badge>
```

To this:

```
    <su:badge layout="5" location="http://www.fairivy.com/"></su:badge>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. It should be marked as so.

Answer (score 1):

you may have to customize that js script that stumblupon provides, try changing this line in the JS, and have it hosted on your own website:

```
if(this.type=='follow')
return scheme+'www.'+ this.domain+ followBase+'?id='+ this.ref+'&l='+ this.layout;else if(this.type=='bestof')
return scheme+'www.'+ this.domain+ bestofBase+'?'+ this.request.join('&')+'&l='+ this.layout+'&title='+ encodeURIComponent(this.title);
```

if you use this solution you may have to make a seperate .js with only your main domain.

you would also need to change this line to your custom location:

```
'//platform.stumbleupon.com/1/widgets.js'
```

Comment: copy the whole javascript file, replace the "this.domain+followBase+'?id='" and "this.domain+ bestofBase+'?'" with simply : "fairivy.com"

Comment: Sorry for being thick, but I'm not even a little bit of a programmer.  I tried what you mentioned but the button disappeared.  I don't think I entered it correctly :(